# Adwhirl not showing ads in released version on app store

Tags: iphone, ios, ads, adwhirl

I made my first application called ImgurViewer and added adWhirl to it. During testing I could see ads show up but when I released the application, ads don't seem to show up in that app store version. I don't get why this would happen.

I can see ads when I run it on xcode or run on my device but the app store build doesn't show ads for some reason.

Anyone has any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: This is likely not an AdWhirl issue, but probably has to do with the ad networks you've chosen to integrate.  A little more information on your set up (and any available logs) will shed more light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I rather use AdMob for your application for google ads try this link especially that Admob is an advertisement SDK that allows you to show advertisements just from google or Admob, it's straight forward, unless you want to use different advertisement channels, AdMob SDK is more stable than AdWhirl SDK:

http://www.admob.com/